# Error after submit form in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

I'm very new in node and mongo and i'm tryin to learn them . here is my simple app and I want to save data with form using **`Jade`** .

**JADE**

```
 form.form-horizontal(method="post", id="loginForm" action="/new")
        label Email
        input.span3(id="email", type="text", name="email", placeholder="Enter your Email")
        label Name
        input.span3(id="name", type="text", name="name", placeholder="Your Name")
        label Age
        input.span3(id="age", type="number", name="age", placeholder="Your Age")
        div.login
            input.btn.warning(type="submit", value="Log In")
```

**app.js**

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mean");

var Schema = new mongoose.Schema(
 {
    _id  :"string",
     name:"string",
     age :"number"
 }
);
var user = mongoose.model("emp", Schema);

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', users.list);

app.post("/new", function(res, req){
    new user({
        _id : req.body.email,
        name: req.body.name,
        age : req.body.age
    }).save(function(err, doc){
            if(err){
                res.json(err);
            }else{
                res.send("Data inserted successfully !");
            }
        });
});
```

after submit i get this error :

```
Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done a basic mistake here, in the line

```
app.post("/new", function(res, req){
```

The first argument(`res`) is actually the `request` object and the second(`req`) is the `response` object. `email` is present in the `request` object that is `res` here. Either change your code to

```
new user({
    _id : res.body.email,
    name: res.body.name,
    age : res.body.age
})
```

Or I would suggest simply swap the arguments like this, and every thing should work:

```
app.post("/new", function(req, res){... //See I swapped the variable, now it should work.
```